# If $r$ is a root of $p(x)$, then $r^2-4$ is also a root of $p(x)$

Tags: polynomials

> Consider polynomials $p(x)$ with the following property, called $(\dagger)$.
> $(\dagger)$ If $r$ is a root of $p(x)$, then $r^2-4$ is also a root of $p(x)$.
> We want to find every quadratic polynomial of the form $p(x)=x^2+b x+c$ such that $p(x)$ has two distinct roots, has integer coefficients and has property $(\dagger)$. Prove that there are exactly two such polynomials and list them.

---

I'm not able to understand the problem correctly as I'm finding $3$ such polynomial.

1. Taking $r=2$, we get $p(x)=(x-2)(x-(2^2 -4))= (x-2)x$
2. Taking $r=-2$, similarly we get $p(x)=(x+2)x$
3. Taking $r=0$, we get $p(x)=(x)(x+4)$

All these 3 polynomials have both $r$ and $r^2 -4$ as distinct roots, and have integer coefficients. But the problems says there's only 3 such polynomials, what am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: You should read the condition as "for $every$ root $r$ of the polynomial, $r^2-4$ is also a root of the polynomial", so you first example does not satisfy the condition, because its roots are $0$ and $2$, and whereas $2^2-4=0$ is a root, $0^2-4=-4$ is not.

Comment: @mcd So then, first we get if $r$ is a root, then $r^2 -4$ is also a root, but then $(r^2-4)^2-4$ is also a root and it goes on recursively?

Comment: Yes, thus the roots have to satisfy $r=(r^2-4)^2-4$. Solve that and if $r$ satisfies that equation, then the polynomials $(x-r)(x-(r^2-4))$ are the desired polynomials.

Comment: It may help to note $r=r^2-4$ directly gives one of the quadratics you seek, and the quartic above has to have that as a factor, so division gives you the other.

Comment: @Macavity but only 2 if the 4 roots shall work right? One of the root we get through $r=r^2 -4$, the and other one we get through the other quadratic polynomial after dividing by $r^2 -4$, but how do we know which 2 roots are our desired ones?

Comment: $r^2-r-4=0$ gives you two distinct roots, each of which satisfy the condition by themselves.  The other quadratic you will have to get by factoring or dividing this away.  That has its two roots linked like $r_1 \to r_2 \to r_1$ as you apply $r^2-4$ each time, you can't mix these roots with the ones from the earlier polynomial obviously.  In fact the integer coefficient condition is not needed here, that would also give you only one possible pairing for each root.  Try it yourself.